# Is it true that にしたって is the colloquial form of にしたところで?

Tags: grammar, words, synonyms, colloquial-language

I've been thinking if it is true that にしたって is the colloquial form of にしたところで. In other words, are the bottom two sentences identical in meaning and nuance?

1) 彼は日本語を20年も勉強しているが、その彼**にしたところで**、まだ分からない文法に時々出くわすそうだ。

2) 彼は日本語を20年も勉強しているが、その彼**にしたって**、まだ分からない文法に時々出くわすそうだ。

> He has studied Japanese for 20 years, but he told me that even he
>   encounters grammar he doesn't understand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The タ-verb (plain past) form + って pattern is most similar, if not identical, to the ～ても pattern:

> そんなこと**言ったって**しょうがない。（＝そんなこと**言っても**しょうがない。） It doesn't help matters to say things like that.
>
> 名前を**変えたって**基本的な問題はそう簡単に消えてくれない。（＝名前を**変えても**基本的な問題はそう簡単に消えてくれない。） Even if you change the name, the fundamental problem won't disappear so easily.

This construction is mostly found in informal speech, whereas ～ても can be used anywhere. **However**, it is important to not confuse the って in this たって pattern with the other use of って, which is an abbreviation of some form of と言う:

> なでしこジャパンが**勝ったって**メールが来た。（＝なでしこジャパンが**勝ったという**メールが来た。） I got a text saying the Nadeshiko won.
>
> 彼は昨日、ドイツから**帰ったって**。（＝彼は昨日、ドイツから**帰ったと言った**。） He said he got back from Germany yesterday.

Comment: heys thanks for the reply =D btw do you mean that にしたって is the colloquial form of にしたところで too ?

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes, I think you could safely make that statement.

Comment: @DerekSchaab can this たって thing be used in places other than after verbs? for example, can it be attached to い-adjectives?