# What's the difference between だって vs にしたって

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I encountered にしたって [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2055/is-it-true-that-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-is-the-colloquial-form-of-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D%E3%81%A7/2056#2056).

> 彼は日本語を20年も勉強しているが、その彼**にしたって**、まだ分からない文法に時々出くわすそうだ。

If the sentence is changed to

> 彼は日本語を20年も勉強しているが、その彼**だって**、まだ分からない文法に時々出くわすそうだ。

does it change the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: Slight inconsistency. Did you mean to ask about the difference between だって and **に**したって or did you mean to add a に to その彼だって?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the difference between だって and にしたって

Answer (score 2, accepted):

にしたって is an informal version of にしたところで ([see examples here](https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18398)).
だって is an informal version of でも.

The constructions にしたところで (にしたって) and でも (だって) mean the same thing in this context, so there is no semantic difference between your sentences. However, they are not always completely interchangeable. As explained in 'A Dictionary of Advanced Japanese Grammar' (p425), にしたところで must be used as the subject, whereas there are times when でも can be used even if it is not the subject. In other words, wherever you see にしたところで (にしたって), you can replace it with でも (だって). But the reverse is not true.